# I'm a guy and I change my appearance to look like my female counterpart

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm a guy and I change my appearance to look like my female counterpart just so that I can physically see someone that could understand and relate with me even from just the mirror. I would wear feminine clothes if I could, but I wouldn't want to wear them always, neither am I gay. I'd probably wear them, look at the mirror then take 'em off afterwards.

What am I called?

Comment: Do you wear makeup, wear feminine clothes? But in the privacy of your home. Do you feel more more comfortable looking at yourself as a female counterpart?   There are many terms to describe a person who is either ambivalent about their sexual identity, or feels misrepresented. I think you should provide a little more context.

Comment: I would wear femenine clothes if I could, but I wouldnt want to wear them always, neither am I gay. Id probably wear them, look at the mirror then take em off afterwards.

Comment: The word is 'author'?

Comment: @HotLicks could you please delete your comment, it just gives homophobics an added excuse to claim that anyone who doesn't conform to the rule: ‘men must dress like men’, is "weird". See also the three inexplicable downvotes. One only has to go back to the 17th century to find the male aristocracy who either wore wigs or their hair long, applied makeup to their faces, and wore exquisite jewellery; no one thought the men were strange then..  http://madameisistoilette.blogspot.it/2013/10/a-beautiful-visage-17th-century-male.html

Comment: @sadpotato Are you sexually aroused by the act of wearing feminine clothes?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - So what is the word for a homophobia-phobic?  (Anyone who doesn't dress in the society-approved fashion is "weird".  Only in the mind of a homophobia-phobic is that term "homophobic".)

Answer (score 8):

Another term is transvestite (employing the same root as "vestments," i.e.  garments): a person, typically a man, who derives pleasure from dressing in clothes appropriate to the opposite sex.

Comment: The UK comedian [Eddie Izzard is a famous transvestite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Izzard#Transvestism), he's explained in interviews that he's heterosexual and there's nothing sexual about how he dresses, it's just how he feels comfortable and what feels right for him. Sounds similar to the asker.

Answer (score 4):

From the information you have given, I think that a close definition of what you are referring to is:

***[Crossdressing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross-dressing):***

> - the wearing of clothes designed for the opposite sex. (M-W)

***[Crossdresser](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crossdresser):***

> - someone who  dresses  in clothing typically worn by members of the opposite sex.

Answer (score 0):

[**drag queen:**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drag-queen)

> A man who ostentatiously dresses up in women’s clothes.

[**drag** (Clothing):](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drag)

> Clothing more conventionally worn by the opposite sex, especially women’s clothes worn by a man:

*'In drag, the men play and create new identities.'*